# Ubuntu: changing mysql datadir issue

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I need to change my datadir and I have succeeded to do so on the main HDD.  I
tried the same manipulation on another mounted HDD and restarting the mysql
fails, I don't understand why. Here is the manipulation I made:

1. editing the my.cnf :

   ```
   datadir         = /var/lib/mysql   ->  datadir = /media/user/BCB3A.../mysql
   ```
2. copying mysql data to the new folder:

   ```
   sudo -s  
   /etc/init.d/mysql stop  
   cp -pr /var/lib/mysql/* /media/user/BCB3A.../mysql
   ```
3. editing apparmor:

   ```
   /var/lib/mysql/ r,                -> /media/user/BCB3A.../mysql/ r,  
   /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,       ->  /media/user/BCB3A/mysql/** rwk,
   ```
4. restarting the services :

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart  
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
   ```

Apparmor restarts properly, but mysql fails.

Looks like I have an issue in the mounting parameters of HDD2 but I don't know
what, any idea?

Comment: You are using `/media/truecrypt4/mysql/` in apparmor.conf but the mysql data dir is `/media/user/BCB3A.../mysql` .. Do you see the difference?

Comment: sorry, mistake when writing,  but the apparmor and mysql datadir are really the same. I edit the post so that it shows it. @hek2mgl

Comment: What says the mysql error log?

Comment: [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it
Then many InnoDB messages, then:
InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
The error means mysqld does not have acess rights to the directory

Comment: ls -l on the new mysql folder shows drxw------ user user
I tried : sudo chmod a+rwx mysql but the ls -l gives same result
I tried sudo chown mysql:mysql /..../mysql but ls -l gives same owner (user) @hek2mgl Thanks a lot for taking time to help :)

Comment: I would copy the data folder using `cp -a`

Comment: I've just tried and got the same issue and same errors in log file

Comment: hard to say without having access to your machine.

Comment: Thanks anyway.... what I noticed is that the /var/lib/mysql is owned by mysql group and user, whereas my other dirs are owned by user/user
So it looks like the chown didn't work. I did like that, was it wrong ? :
sudo -s
chown -R mysql:mysql /media/user/BCB3A.../mysql

Comment: The chown executes properly but when I display with ls -l, the user/group remains user:user

Comment: That's why I suggested `cp -a` because it preserves the ownership. Let me try it locally ...

Comment: I ve deleted and copied again, the ownership is not preserved. The copied folder is owned by user:user despite the source is mysql:mysql

Comment: Could reproduce it locally and got it! You need to make sure that the parent folder: `/media/user/BCB3A...` is browsable (executable) by the mysql user

Comment: ok it must be that.... how can I give exe permission to mysql user on this disk ? (sorry but I'm not advanced enough in command line :/ )

Comment: `sudo chmod o+x /media/user/BCB3A..`

Comment: oh ok I understand what you mean... I already tried sudo chmod a+rwx on the folder but I keep having drwx------
I have correct rights for user, but not for group and others, it keeps -

Comment: hmm, then I fear I can't help more..

Comment: wow, I found it!!!! that was so obvious .... the second HDD is partitioned in NTFS that's why I can't change permissions/owners... !!! Thanks a lot, without your help I wouldn't have found it.

Comment: Ah ok! Hadn't this in mind :) I suggest that you answer your own question, it may help others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple actually....

The mysql folder needs to be owned by mysql:mysql.
sudo chown mysql:mysql /your_new_mysql_dir/

In my case this command was not changing the ownership for the simple reason that the file system of the secondary hard disk drive was NTFS, and permissions/ownership is not applyable on NTFS, so a format into FAT32 fixed the issue.
Thanks to @hek2mgl for the big help!

Comment: ntfs allows posix permissions as i understood. Now i set and see 'mysql' as owner and group for my new mysql data folder and all containments, but i cannot run server whatever. Is ntfs the reason?